# Git merge conflict reset everything

Tags: git, github

I had to roll back the Live server and now I'm getting conflict errors when trying to merge my dev branch with master as they are out of sync.

Is there any way of simply resetting everything so I can merge dev with master?

Dev is correct and I'm happy to Overwrite master but don't want to work out all the conflicts through mergetool if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what is your goal, there are two options:

```
git checkout dev
git merge -s ours master
```

It leaves the merged result to be **exactly** the `dev`, really, it just marks `master` as a parent of `dev` but do nothing to `dev` in source level.

Or

```
git checkout dev
git merge -X ours master
```

It do a merge as usual, but automatically use the piece from `dev` if there is a conflict. That means, if something `master` introduced conflicts with `dev`, it prefers `dev`, but with those does **NOT** conflict, it involves them in merged result.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to wipe away master and change master to match you dev branch.  If this is the case this will work (WARNING any changes not on dev will be gone):

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard dev
```

Comment: This is destructive, i.e., throws away the history of master, which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your dev branch is usually ahead of master, so you want to (formally) merge master back into dev, but keep everything in dev as it is. This can be done as follows:

```
git checkout dev
git merge -s ours -m 'formal no-op merge of changes from master' master
```